# How to install liquibase on redhat linux

Tags: redhat, liquibase, headless

Thought this might help others. If you are running a headless VM it might not be immediately evident how to install liquibase. I was using a redhat linux box and wondering which command to try to install liquibase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to another computer with a browser. Go to http://www.liquibase.org/download and copy the path to the liquibase zip file. Paste that path onto a wget command as in the example below

`wget https://github.com/downloads/liquibase/liquibase/liquibase-2.0.5-bin.zip`

unzip the zip file in the location of your choice such as ~/liquibase

Once you are done you will have to manually create your liquibase.properties file.